# c++ vector pointer does not have correct size vector<Object>* ptr, ptr->size is wrong

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, garbage

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Student // EdgeContainer
{
    string name = "";
    vector<string> *addresses = nullptr;
    Student()
    {
        cout << __FILE__ << " " << __LINE__ << " Student()" << endl;
    }

    Student(const Student &stu)
    {
        cout << __FILE__ << " " << __LINE__ << " Student(const Student &stu)" << endl;
        name = stu.name;
        addresses = stu.addresses;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << name << " " << addresses << " size=" << addresses->size() << endl;
        if (addresses != nullptr)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < addresses->size(); i++)
            {
                cout << i << " " << (*addresses)[i] << endl;
            }
        }
        cout << "----------------\n";
    }
};

struct Printer //ToyView
{
    vector<Student *> students;
    vector<vector<string>> stu_addresses;
    void add_student()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            vector<string> address;
            address.push_back("addr1");
            address.push_back("addr2");
            stu_addresses.push_back(address);
            Student *stu = new Student;
            students.push_back(stu);
            students[i]->name = "stu" + to_string(i);
            students[i]->addresses = &stu_addresses[i];
            cout << i << " stu->address=" << stu->addresses << " size=" << stu->addresses->size() << endl;
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << " students size=" << students.size() << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << i << " stu->address=" << students[i]->addresses << endl;
            // students[i]->addresses = &stu_addresses[i];
            students[i]->print();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Printer printer;
    printer.add_student();
    printer.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is some result:

```
../vector_cp.cpp 13 Student()
0 stu->address=0x563888ac6f30 size=2
../vector_cp.cpp 13 Student()
1 stu->address=0x563888ac7418 size=2
../vector_cp.cpp 13 Student()
2 stu->address=0x563888ac74f0 size=2
../vector_cp.cpp 13 Student()
3 stu->address=0x563888ac7508 size=2
../vector_cp.cpp 13 Student()
4 stu->address=0x563888ac76c0 size=2
../vector_cp.cpp 13 Student()
5 stu->address=0x563888ac76d8 size=2
../vector_cp.cpp 13 Student()
6 stu->address=0x563888ac76f0 size=2
../vector_cp.cpp 13 Student()
7 stu->address=0x563888ac7708 size=2
../vector_cp.cpp 13 Student()
8 stu->address=0x563888ac7a10 size=2
../vector_cp.cpp 13 Student()
9 stu->address=0x563888ac7a28 size=2
 students size=10
0 stu->address=0x563888ac6f30
stu0 0x563888ac6f30 size=18446744073709549283
```

I expect students[0]->addresses.size() should be 2, but it shows the garbage number.
After uncomment this line
// students[i]->addresses = &stu_addresses[i];
The code actually works, which is  students[0]->addresses.size().
I still cannot figure out why this works. Can anyone help?

Comment: why is `vector<string> *addresses` not a `std::vector<string>` ?

Comment: I don't know if that pointer is the reason for your problem, but definitely it makes the code much more complicated than necessary. For example `addresses = stu.addresses;` in the copy constructor is a recipe for desaster (you just dont notice it because you are leaking the memory)

Comment: You store addresses of vector elements. If the vector get's resized it might reallocate and the stored pointers will be invalidated. In modern C++ you want to avoid raw pointers as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
stu_addresses.push_back(address);
// ...
students[i]->addresses = &stu_addresses[i];
```

Pushing back elements in `stu_addresses` might reallocate your vector and previously-valid pointer/iterators on `stu_addresses` elements will be invalidated.

Cf. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Iterator_invalidation